# Use OpenVPN Server through a port in a VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps, openvpn

I'm trying to configure my **OpenVPN Server** to be used by an **OpenVPN Client** and the **Admin Panel** through a port, because my IP is already being used by **VestaCP** (also hosted in my VPS) to host a Webpage, and when I try to use that port to access the **Admin Panel** through it, I'm redirected to the page.